# clojure: stack overflow over range

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow

I am trying to solve problem 60 at 4clojure.com

[sequence reductions](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/60)

my solution works for the last two cases but fails for the first case in handling range.

here is my solution

```
(fn reds
([func lst](if (empty? lst)
           []
           (reds func (first lst) (rest lst))))
([func init lst](if (empty? lst)
           (println "hi")
           (concat [init] (reds func (func init (first lst)) (rest lst)))))
)
```

I think this is because I keep calling the function on more terms of an infinite list . but how do I do better?

update : solved it using lazy-seq

Comment: "and the return sequence must be lazy"

Comment: how do I make it lazy ?

Comment: no worries. just learnt about lazy-seq

Comment: You can answer your own question by showing your code which can help others.